# Appcelerator Alloy ignores platform specific code

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have written the following code:

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    function showDialog() {
        // Android logic
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        // Android logic
    }
}

if (OS_IOS) {
    function showDialog() {
        // iOS logic
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        // iOS logic
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run on Android it executes the code for iOS. So when I had a look at the generated files in the resources directory I see that generated code just removes the `if (OS_ANDROID)` and `if (OS_IOS)` blocks and leaves both codes (iOS and Android) on the file.

Currently I'm running on the emulators, but I'm guessing it should work just the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not **Titanium** issue you are running into, rather it's a **JavaScript** programming error you are doing here, & solution to this error is called as **[JavaScript's Function Hoisting](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/scoping-and-hoisting-in-javascript-2c2e82107427)**

You cannot just simply declare functions inside **if-else** conditions because **if-else** is a **block** & **blocks** do not contain **function declarations.**

That's why **Titanium** resources files are showing both methods because methods are not allowed to be declared inside **if-else**, and if you do, then they will be considered as in global scope or more accurately in the parent scope of **if-else.**

So, you can make your code work like this:

```
function showDialog() {
    if (OS_IOS) {
       // ios logic

    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
       // android logic
    }
}

function closeDialog() {
    if (OS_IOS) {
       // ios logic

    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
       // android logic
    }
}
```